# Can't launch exe with process start

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to replicate the start menu, I can get the paths to all the applications no problem. And have managed to get the path to target exe for shortcuts. I can launch most of them without any issues, but some of them (one currently, but I'd assume they'll be more) fail with the below error

> Error => "The instruction at {hex} referenced memory at {hex}. The memory
>   could not be read"

I've tried

```
Process.Start(pathToMyExe);

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pathToMyExe);
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToMyExe);
Process.Start(processStartInfo);

ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe");
processStartInfo.Arguments = "/c \"" + pathToMyExe + "\"";
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

Some of these came back with the above error, some did nothing at all. The file I'm trying to launch is

> Acrobat Reader DC

which is located at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe

on my machine. It launches fine from the start menu, and if I double click on it in explorer.

I've looked at all the other questions about similar problems, non of the solutions seem to work for this. Anyone got any ides of a way around this?

Comment: Why are you opening "AcroRd32.exe" by passing it as parameter to cmd.exe? Why not start it directly?

Comment: @Carbine, I think the OP is showing *three* different ways they've attempted to launch `acrord32.exe` to resolve the issues they're seeing (`Process.Start`, `Process.Start` via a `ProcessStartInfo` and via `cmd.exe`), not suggesting that their *intention* is to always open apps by passing them via `cmd.exe` =)

Comment: Your problem isn't reproducible. `Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 2015\Reader\AcroRd32.exe")` works fine on my machine (although the path is slightly different).

Comment: @Rob - That's right, first tried opening it with process start, then tried other methods, since that didn't work for me.

Comment: @Clemens I'll have to try it on a another PC then, see if there's something up with my setup. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine in both a console application and a WPF application.

```
var exePath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
new Process {StartInfo = {FileName = exePath}}.Start();
```